# run Metro application on Windows 7.5 mobile

Tags: windows-phone-7, microsoft-metro

Hello I've just received HTC Mazaa with Windows Mobile 7.5
Is there any possibility tu run Windows Metro application on this phone ?

Question may sound stupid but Windows Mobile 7.x has similar interface and Metro apps should run on pc, tablets and phones. I'm wondering is the similarity beetwen win mobile 7 and 8 is only interface or maybe the core is also similar ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/710/106

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this is not possible on current Windows Phone 7.x

there might be some interpolation / code sharing between Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 but running an app written for 1 in another will not be possible even then.

Comment: Listen most developers i have talked to will continue making apps for 7.x in coming months. I dont see any issues relating to app availability once WP8 is out.

Comment: I`m not afraid about that. ATM I`m developing win8 application and I was hoping that I`ll be able to check it on something else than PC and Tablet emulator. You know real device is something else than emulator. Thats all :)

Comment: aah you could buy a small test device something like w500. i am going with emulator which is just a remote desktop view for now